# Identify last document from MongoDB find() result set

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to 'stream' data from a node.js/MongoDB instance to the client using websockets. It is all working well.

But how to I identify the last document in the result? I'm using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) to connect to MongoDB from node.js.

A simplified example:

```
collection.find({}, {}, function(err, cursor) {
  if (err) sys.puts(err.message);

  cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    client.send(doc);
  });                
});
```

Comment: This might not be the best approach to streaming documents from the DB—e.g. what if the documents are inserted faster than you can query them this way? See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since mongodb objectId contatins creation date you can sort by id, descending and then use limit(1):

```
db.collection.find().sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1);
```

Note: i am not familiar with node.js at all, above command is mongo shell command and i suppose you can easy rewrite it to node.js.

Comment: It's not the case when objects are created more often than one second, because ObjectId contains 4-byte value representing the **seconds** since the Unix epoch.

Comment: @EddieJamsession In theory yes, but have you tested this?

Comment: db.collection.find().limit(1).sort( { _id : -1 } );                               //just now i have tested.. sort should be last method.

Answer (score 1):

Say I have companies collection. Below snippet gives me last document in the collection.

```
db.companies.find({},{"_id":1}).skip(db.companies.find().count()-1);
```

Code cannot rely on _id as it may not be on a specific pattern always if it's a user defined value.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort and limit, if you want to use cursor :

```
var last = null;
var findCursor = collection.find({}).cursor();
findCursor.on("data", function(data) {
   last = data;
   ...
});
findCursor.on("end", function(data) {
   // last result in last
   ....
});
```