# Why won't my insert callback run?

Tags: mongodb

I'm running the following from the mongodb console (it's in a js file called via `load()`), but the callback to the `insert` never runs even though all the database insertions happen as expected. Can anyone see why?

```
db.oldsets.find().forEach(function (set) {
    var newSet = {
        tunes: [],
        keys: []
    };
    set.tunes.forEach(function (arr) {
        if (newSet) {
            var tune = db.oldtunes.findOne({
                _id: arr.tune
            })
            var newTune = db.getSiblingDB('jnr_local').tunes.findOne({
                sessionId: tune.sessionId
            })
            if (newTune) {
                newSet.tunes.push(newTune._id);
                newSet.keys.push(arr.root + tune.mode);
            } else {
                newSet = null;
            }
        }
    })
    print('out') // outputs for every iteration
    if (newSet) {
        db.sets.insert(newSet, function (err, doc) {
            print('in') // never outputs
            db.practices.insert({
                type: 'set',
                // srcId: doc[0]._id,
                stickyness: 0
            });    
        }); 

    } else {
        print('else') // never outputs
        db.dodgySets.insert(set); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think mongo shell conforms to node.js api. Meaning there are no callbacks. http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert

Comment: This is the best I've found so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789001/identify-last-document-from-mongodb-find-result-set

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing `node.js` and `mongodb shell`. In mongodb shell all code is synchronous and run line by line.

So the `db.sets.insert` will simply return inserted document.

So, try to rewrite it as follow:

```
if (newSet) {
      insertedSet = db.sets.insert(newSet);
      print('in') // never outputs
      db.practices.insert({
        type: 'set',
        srcId: insertedSet._id,
        stickyness: 0
      });    
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't - it returns an object which has a count of how many documents were inserted. And `.insert()` doesn't add the `_id` property to newSet either. I resorted to trying asynchronous stuff only after nothing synchronous seemed to work.

Comment: But thanks for pointing out the nodejs vs shell distinction. The documentation sites don't do a very good job of doing so.