# How to use limit in mongodb and NodeJS query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, express, limit

I want to extract only 1 document from mongo db 'property' collection. 
It should also be the latest document.
It looks very simple but I dont know why my query is not retrieving number of document specified in limit.

**ORIGINAL METHOD**: This query extracts all documents

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){      
    db.property.find(function (err, docs) {
    res.render("index.ejs",{property: docs});
  })
});
```

**EDIT 1**: This query extracts nothing

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){       
     db.property.find( {sort: {created_at: -1}, limit: 1}, function (err, docs) {
     res.render("index.ejs",{property: docs});
   })
});
```

**EDIT 2**: This query gives correct 1 document but I want the latest one now.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){       
     db.property.find({}).limit(2).toArray(function (err, docs) {
     res.render("index.ejs",{property: docs});
   })
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789001/identify-last-document-from-mongodb-find-result-set

Answer (score 5):

I tried modifying query in several ways and finally I got its solution

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){       
    db.property.find({}).sort({timestamp: -1}).limit(1).toArray(function (err, docs) {
     res.render("index.ejs",{property: docs});
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Property = require('../models/property');

var q = Property.find().sort({created_at: -1}).limit(1);
    q.exec(function(err, property) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(property);
    });
```

Can you try this, let me if there is any issue on the result.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: q.exec is not a function. Is there any dependencies I am missing?
I am new to nodejs and mongodb

Comment: First you need to import your model using "require".

`var Property = require('../models/property');`

You can fetch the record using the variable 'Property'.

`var q = Property.find().sort({created_at: -1}).limit(1);
    q.exec(function(err, prop) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(prop);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one that I use to sort:

```
db.projectadmins.find({}).projection({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(100)
```